# Pandas: How can I do cross validation without using scikit?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-analysis, data-science

I am trying to implement my own cross-validation function. I read about cross-validation on this [link](http://genome.tugraz.at/proclassify/help/pages/XV.html), and was able to split my dataset into training and test. However how can I define the folds?
For example my data frame looks like this.

```
    Dataframe:
        MMC         MET_lep     MASS_Vis    Pt_H        Y
    0   138.70      51.65       97.82       0.91        0
    1   160.93      68.78       103.23      -999.00     0
    2   -999.00     162.17      125.95      -999.00     0
    3   143.90      81.41       80.94       -999.00     1
    4   175.86      16.91       134.80      -999.00     0
    5   -999.00     162.17      125.95      -999.00     0
    6   143.90      81.41       80.94       -999.00     1
    7   175.86      16.91       134.80      -999.00     0
    8   -999.00     162.17      125.95      -999.00     0
    9   143.90      81.41       80.94       -999.00     1
```

And want output like this:

```
For    K=3 (Folds)

When K=1
Training:
            MMC         MET_lep     MASS_Vis    Pt_H        Y
        0   138.70      51.65       97.82       0.91        0
        1   160.93      68.78       103.23      -999.00     0
        2   -999.00     162.17      125.95      -999.00     0
        3   143.90      81.41       80.94       -999.00     1
        4   175.86      16.91       134.80      -999.00     0
        5   -999.00     162.17      125.95      -999.00     0
        6   143.90      81.41       80.94       -999.00     1
Test:
        7   175.86      16.91       134.80      -999.00     0
        8   -999.00     162.17      125.95      -999.00     0
        9   143.90      81.41       80.94       -999.00     1

When K=2
Training:
            MMC         MET_lep     MASS_Vis    Pt_H        Y
        0   138.70      51.65       97.82       0.91        0
        1   160.93      68.78       103.23      -999.00     0
        2   -999.00     162.17      125.95      -999.00     0
        6   143.90      81.41       80.94       -999.00     1
        7   175.86      16.91       134.80      -999.00     0
        8   -999.00     162.17      125.95      -999.00     0
        9   143.90      81.41       80.94       -999.00     1

Test:
        3   143.90      81.41       80.94       -999.00     1
        4   175.86      16.91       134.80      -999.00     0
        5   -999.00     162.17      125.95      -999.00     0

When K=3
Training:
            MMC         MET_lep     MASS_Vis    Pt_H        Y
        0   138.70      51.65       97.82       0.91        0
        1   160.93      68.78       103.23      -999.00     0
        2   -999.00     162.17      125.95      -999.00     0
        3   143.90      81.41       80.94       -999.00     1
        7   175.86      16.91       134.80      -999.00     0
        8   -999.00     162.17      125.95      -999.00     0
        9   143.90      81.41       80.94       -999.00     1
Test:
        4   175.86      16.91       134.80      -999.00     0
        5   -999.00     162.17      125.95      -999.00     0
        6   143.90      81.41       80.94       -999.00     1
```

Below is my code, it does the job of splitting but does not do the folds:

```
 split = math.floor(dataset.shape[0]*0.8)
    data_train = dataset[:split]
    data_test = dataset[split:]
```

Thank you in advance for helping on this.

Answer (score 7):

Is it your intention for the K=2 fold to overlap with the K=3 test fold (3,4,5) vs (4,5,6)? Also, it seems like K is being overloaded in your example to mean both the number of folds, and the index of the current fold.  In my answer, I'll use i for the i-th fold out of k total folds.

Assuming the goal is to create non-overlapping folds, it should be sufficient to have a function that produces roughly even ranges out of the range 0 to len(dataset) - 1.  You can get a roughly even split even when your list is not perfectly divisible by k splitting at floor((n*i)/k).  In python you could use a function like this:

```
def fold_i_of_k(dataset, i, k):
    n = len(dataset)
    return dataset[n*(i-1)//k:n*i//k]
```

Here is an example on a one dimensional data-set (should work just as well for a DataFrame):

```
>>> fold_i_of_k(list(range(0,11)),1,3)
[0, 1, 2]
>>> fold_i_of_k(list(range(0,11)),2,3)
[3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> fold_i_of_k(list(range(0,11)),3,3)
[7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Thanks! Great answer, just note that You have an extra parenthesis on the `return` line: it should be `n*(i-1)//k`, not `n*(i-1))//k`. I confirmed that it works great on a pandas.DataFrame :)

Answer (score 3):

this solution is based on pandas and numpy libraries:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

First you split your dataset into k parts:

```
k = 10
folds = np.array_split(data, k)
```

Then you iterate over your folds, using one as testset and the other k-1 as training, so at last you perform the fitting k times:

```
for i in range(k):
    train = folds.copy() // you wanna work on a copy of your array
    test = folds[i]
    del train[i]
    train = pd.concat(train, sort=False)
    perform(clf, train.copy(), test.copy()) // do the fitting, here you also want to copy
```

In this function you remove the label column from your sets and fit the scikit-classifier (clf) and then return the prediction.

```
def perform(clf, train_set, test_set):
    # remove labels from data
    train_labels = train_set.pop('Y').values
    test_labels = test_set.pop('Y').values
    clf.fit(train_set, train_labels)
    return clf.score(test_set, test_labels)
```

Comment: instead spliting the array, it would be better if you could get the indexes and iterate the array using those indexes